# Get the object which failed validation Spring Batch validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-batch, bean-validation

I am having this task to process input .csv, .txt files and store the data into a database. I am using Spring Batch for this purpose. Before dumping the data into database, I have to perform some validation checks on the data. I am using Spring Batch's `ValidatingItemProcessor` and Hibernate's `JSR-303` reference implementation hibernate validator for the same. The code looks something like:

```
public class Person{

@Pattern(regexp = "someregex")
String name;
@NotNull
String address;
@NotNull
String age;

//getters and setters

}
```

And then I wrote a validator which looks something like this --

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

import org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

import org.springframework.batch.item.validator.Validator;

 class MyBeanValidator implements Validator<Person>, InitializingBean{

   private javax.validation.Validator validator;

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            validator = validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Person person) throws ValidationException {
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations =  validator.validate(person);

            if(constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
                generateValidationException(constraintViolations);
            }

        }
private void generateValidationException(Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>>   constraintViolations) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            for (ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
                message.append(constraintViolation.getMessage() + "\n");
            }

            throw new ValidationException(message.toString());
}
```

And then I have a processor which subclasses Spring Batch's `ValidatingItemProcessor`.

```
 public class ValidatingPersonItemProcessor extends    ValidatingItemProcessor<Person>{


@Override
public Person process(Person person) {

//some code
 }
```

The records that pass validation checks would be passed on to another processor for further processing but the failed ones will be cleaned and then passed on to next processor.

1. Now I want to catch hold of records which failed validation. My objective is to report all input records that failed validation and clean those records further before I could pass on those records to next processor for further processing. How can I achieve this?
2. Will the Spring Batch process terminate if validation fails for some input? If yes, how to avoid that? My Processor configuration looks something like :

   ```
   <batch:chunk reader="personItemReader" writer="personDBWriter"  processor="personProcessor"
               commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100">
               <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                   <batch:include   class="org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidationException"/>
               </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
               <batch:listeners>
                   <batch:listener>
                       <bean
                              class="org.someorg.poc.batch.listener.PersonSkipListener" />
                   </batch:listener>
               </batch:listeners>
           </batch:chunk>
   <bean id="personProcessor"
   class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
     <property name="delegates">
       <list>
         <ref bean="validatingPersonItemProcessor" />
         <ref bean="personVerifierProcessor" />
      </list>
     </property>
   </bean>
      <bean id="validatingPersonItemProcessor" class="org.someorg.poc.batch.processor.ValidatingPersonItemProcessor" scope="step">
      <property name="validator" ref="myBeanValidator" />
      </bean>

        <bean id="myBeanValidator" class="org.someorg.poc.batch.validator.MyBeanValidator">
   </bean>

       <bean id="personVerifierProcessor" class="org.someorg.poc.batch.processor.PersonVerifierProcessor"     scope="step"/>
      </beans>
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a report on filtered items in spring-batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999435/how-to-create-a-report-on-filtered-items-in-spring-batch)

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318466/spring-batch-how-to-filter-duplicated-items-before-send-it-to-itemwriter

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks for the comment. How to filter an exception as SkipException in ItemProcessor? Also as you may see, I am generating exception from my validator and not processor. Should I change this behavior?

Comment: Read SB documentation about item filtering and skippable exception; start from linked aswers and you will find all answers.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `validatingPersonItemProcessor` bean has his validator parameter set with your `myBeanValidator`. So the `Exception` will be thrown by the processor.

Create your own [SkipListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/SkipListener.html). Here you put the logic on what happens when an item is not validated (writtes to a file, a DB, etc.), in the `onSkipInProcess();`.

You need to add the `ValidationException` you throw in `<batch:skippable-exception-classes>` so they will be caught (and doesn't terminate your batch), and add your SkipListener in the `<batch:listeners>`, so it will be call when an exception is thrown.

EDIT: Answer to comment.
If your processor is a [ValidatingItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/ValidatingItemProcessor.html)  and you set the validator, it should automatically call validate. However if you make your own `ValidatingItemProcessor` by extending it, you should explicitely call `super.process(yourItem);` ([`process()` of ValidatingItemProcessor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/2.1.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/ValidatingItemProcessor.java#ValidatingItemProcessor.process%28java.lang.Object%29) ) to validate your item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did all the above. But I am throwing exception from my validator. So do I need to explicitly call validate() method of my Validator from Processor?? Should it not be called automatically on its own?? At present I am confused as to how to get the validation right.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just one last thing. I am using ValidationException in my skippable section configuration inside chunk. But the faulty input still goes to the next processor in chain. My filter is set to false. Should not the faulty input be skipped and caught by my SkipListener which I registered with my chunk.

Comment: Sounds weird. Your `SkipItemListener` gets the `ValidaitonException` but the `CompositeItemProcessor` stills calls the `personVerifierProcessor` ?

Comment: The 'SkipItemListener' is not kicking at all. I read the docs that it does not kick in immediately but it I am afraid it is not kicking at all. I am having a faulty input which proceeds ahead to next processor in chain and this processor('personVerifierProcessor') is passing it to Writer which throws me an exception as I expect input in a particular format only. If I set 'filter = true', it will rather filter the input and I don't want that since I have to report the faulty input back.

Comment: I have written my SkipItemListener inside the chunk. I think I should once try moving it out from the chunk and see if makes any difference.

Comment: What's your `skip-limit` and `commit-interval` ? Or post the whole new configuration file. I don't see how the `validatingPersonItemProcessor` can throw an exception and the `personVerifierProcessor` is still called with the same item.

Comment: Edited my question to include more configuration. You can now see my chunk interval and skip limit there. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Mh, honestly I don't see anything wrong. Do you go above the 100 skip limit in your test ? You should put a bigger number if you expect more item to be invalidated. How do you see that the validating processor throws an Exception ?

Comment: I am testing this functionality with input file containing only 5 records. So I am well within the skip limit. And I am using regex to see if input string contains integers only and I am deliberately introducing characters in between. So I can see in logs that ValidationException appears but then it goes to next processor and then to writer too which throws exception as it was expecting string containing integers only. I was converting that string to BigDecimal when it threw a NumberFormatException as string had characters in between.

Comment: Is it because the `validatingPersonItemProcessor` is not able to re-throw `ValidationException`? I have no code written for re throwing exception from processor as I have read in the docs that the processor does it on its own.

Comment: As long as `validatingPersonItemProcessor` doesn't catch the exception thrown by its validator it should work. Maybe you could add its code to your post ?

Comment: Exactly. And I noticed an evil try-catch block surrounding super.process(); Removed it and working now. But now getting `org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipLimitExceededException: Skip limit of '100' exceeded`. In a record of 3 files I don't know why processor is trying to process it again and again. I have a scheduler which is currently launching the of all this processing in every 1 minute. May be due to that I am getting such overwhelming read, process and write logs. Trying to figure out.

Comment: 100 might not be enough, depending on how many line you're reading/expecting to fail. You can even set a skip policy so that there is no limit.

Comment: I am just testing the functionality with mere 3-5 records. But the reader and processor keep stuck on the first record of the file (which I am fetching from DB as of now as I have dumped all the data into DB) itself which is erroneous. In process, it exceeds the current skip limit of 100 and the job fails as it does not skip and move on to next records in the file. Why should it stuck on the first record itself? I have checked my scheduler too. There is nothing wrong there.

Comment: Spring has the ability to retry failed steps/item, maybe you've set something to activate this behavior ?

Comment: I am not sure. Looking if Spring Batch is doing something on its own. However I feel highly unlikely of the same.